# Starting service Service Bus Message Broker failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed

Tags: sharepoint-2013

when I ran the workflow manager getting the error message at add host to service bus farm.
We have the SharePoint as standalone, OS is Windows server 2012 r2
SQL server 2016 developer.

Followed below two url's for installing 
https://collab365.community/configuring-sharepoint-2013-to-support-workflow-management/
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/workflow-manager-configuration-for-sharepoint-server-2013/ unable to under stand the issue where exactly.

please find the below log file 
[Verbose] [12/10/2018 4:43:54 PM]: Service Bus services starting.
[Progress] [12/10/2018 4:43:54 PM]: Service Bus services starting.
[Error] [12/10/2018 4:53:55 PM]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Starting service Service Bus Message Broker failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed. ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Starting service Service Bus Message Broker failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SCMHelper.StartService(String serviceName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout, String hostName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusConfigHelper.StartSBServices(String hostName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.AddSBHost.ProcessRecordImplementation()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`3 updateProgress)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddSBNode(FarmCreationModel model, Boolean isFirstCommand)

please let me know how to resolve this issue for installing the workflowmanager.

Comment: It's a helpful post **[Service Bus Message Broker Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/)**

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was enabling TLS 1.0 in the registry.

in my case I don't have registry of client but only enabled the server one

**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001**

**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001**

fyi... I was stopped the Service Bus Message Broker while the workflow manager configuration wizard was running in the "add host to service bus fam" task, then the changes the wizard complete successfully. I hope so much you can resolve this issue :)

this is the link where I fund the answers http://answersweb.azurewebsites.net/MVC/Post/Thread/e6667e72-36db-44d7-bcb9-0d537cd19542?category=workflow and is the CRBenson post, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same issue. Installing the [correct patch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496) fixed the issue.

Complete details on below thread.

http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2021/02/service-bus-gateway-service-stuck-at.html